# Changing logo on scroll pushes menu items down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The site I'm working is suposed to change the logo location and size, from top to the far left, and incidentally shrink the navbar to fit the new size, when the user is scrolling down. I've managed to get it to work with javascript but now a different problem ocurred: when the logo is repositioned to the left it pushes the menu items below.

To better illustrate it here's a fiddle:    https://jsfiddle.net/resch/d6vfertf/3/

What I want is when the user scrolls down, the logo goes to the far left of the menu but the menu items stay in the middle (vertically speaking) of the navbar.

**NOTE:** This blog illustrates perfectly what I am trying to do: http://www.depoisdosquinze.com/

Couldn't find my answer here, please feel free to mark as duplicate and vote to close if this is already answered.
Thank you!

```js
var $header = $("nav.navbar");
var $logo = $("a.logo");
var $li = $("ul.navbar-nav > li");
var $img = $("img#logo");
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var e = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (e > 90) {
    $header.css("height", "60px");
    $img.css("max-width", "180px");
    $logo.removeClass('logo');
    $logo.addClass('logo.scroll');
    $li.addClass('scroll');
  } else {
    $header.css("height", "120px");
    $img.css("max-width", "300px");
    $logo.removeClass('logo.scroll');
    $logo.addClass('logo');
    $li.removeClass('scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
img#logo {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: none;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  height: 120px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav>li.scroll {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed !important;
}

.logo.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -160px !important;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 3;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #beb5ac !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #ded8d2 !important;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #29292c !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  .logo {
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a id="brand" class="logo" href="teste3.html">
        <img id="logo" src="https://s4.postimg.org/3tdea6k19/logo2.png" alt=""></a>
      <div class="navbar-header navbar-header-center">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="index"><a href="teste3.html">INÍCIO</a></li>
          <li class="sobre"><a href="teste3_about.html">SOBRE</a></li>
          <li class="ilustracao"><a href="teste3.html#ilustracao">ILUSTRAÇÃO</a></li>
          <li class="design"><a href="teste3.html#design">DESIGN GRÁFICO</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you scroll down your `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">`, it stays full width. The quickest way to solve the problem you need to display in inline i.e. add `display: inline-block` to it. If the style is not persistent add `!important` to it.

However, it is a good idea to avoid using `!important` in your code. I will suggest reading about flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as it will make it easier to implement changes without using `!importtant` in your code.

Froggy http://flexboxfroggy.com is also helpful to learn flexbox. I hope this helps.

Comment: well i tried like you suggested but and it worked! But it also aligned menu items left and I can't get them to align in the center.

Comment: It is not centered because the width of the `ul` is as big as its `li`. The `ul` needs to take the rest of the width and then the `li` can get centered. At the moment you are using `px` for width and more responsive navigation will be if you use `%` so that the Image and Navigation take all of the space and divide it let's say 20% for the image and 80% for the navigation. It will be much easier if you rewrite it with flexbox. Have a go don't worry it is straightforward :-)